# How to partially fill a progressBar when returning from an activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

My main activity consists of 7 buttons which all lead to a different activity, where the user has to type data.

```
public class DiagramNew extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mStateOne;
    Button mStateTwo;
    Button mStateThree;
    Button mStateFour;
    Button mQPump;
    Button mQTurb;
    Button mTemp;
    Button mTester;
    ProgressBar mProgress;
    MotherDatabase myDbMain;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diagram_new);

    myDbMain = new MotherDatabase(this, null, null, 8);


    //Link each .xml component with the activity
    mStateOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stateOneBtn);
    mStateTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stateTwoBtn);
    mStateThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stateThreeBtn);
    mStateFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stateFourBtn);
    mQPump = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QPumpBtn);
    mQTurb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QTurbBtn);
    mTemp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TempBtn);
    mTester = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);





    //Create OnClickListeners for each button
    mStateOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent changeAskOne = new Intent(DiagramNew.this, DataStateOne.class);
            startActivity(changeAskOne);


        }
    });

    mStateTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent changeAskTwo = new Intent(DiagramNew.this, DataStateTwo.class);


            startActivity(changeAskTwo);


        }
    });

    mStateThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent changeAskThree = new Intent(DiagramNew.this, DataStateThree.class);
            startActivity(changeAskThree);
        }
    });

    mStateFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent changeAskFour = new Intent(DiagramNew.this, DataStateFour.class);
            startActivity(changeAskFour);

        }
    });

    mQPump.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent changeAskPump = new Intent(DiagramNew.this, DataPump.class);
            startActivity(changeAskPump);

        }
    });

    mQTurb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent changeAskTurb = new Intent(DiagramNew.this, DataTurb.class);
            startActivity(changeAskTurb);

        }
    });

    mTemp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent changeTemp = new Intent(DiagramNew.this, DataTemp.class);
            startActivity(changeTemp);
        }
    });


    mTester.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkLength();


        }
    });




}
```

When the user returns to the Diagram activity by hitting a button, I want the progressBar to fill up a bit . Here's what the secondary activities look like:

```
public class DataStateOne extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mS1ActualEnthalpy;
EditText mS1IdealEnthalpy;
EditText mS1ActualEntropy;
Button mSaveS1;
Button mDeleteS1;
MotherDatabase myDb;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_state_one);

    mS1ActualEnthalpy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.S1ActualEnthalpyInput);
    mS1IdealEnthalpy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.S1IdealEnthalpyInput);
    mS1ActualEntropy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.S1ActualEntropyInput);
    mSaveS1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveS1Btn);
    mDeleteS1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myDb = new MotherDatabase(this, null, null, 1);

    mS1ActualEnthalpy.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.shadowEnd), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    mS1IdealEnthalpy.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.shadowEnd), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    mS1ActualEntropy.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.shadowEnd), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    mSaveS1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mS1ActualEnthalpy.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && mS1IdealEnthalpy.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && mS1ActualEntropy.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0){
                String S1ActualEnthalpyStr = mS1ActualEnthalpy.getText().toString();
                String S1IdealEnthalpyStr = mS1IdealEnthalpy.getText().toString();
                String S1ActualEntropyStr = mS1ActualEntropy.getText().toString();

                Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The data are " + S1ActualEnthalpyStr + ", " + S1IdealEnthalpyStr + ", " + S1ActualEntropyStr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                myToast.show();

                addButtonClicked();


                Intent returnToDiagram = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DiagramNew.class);

                startActivity(returnToDiagram);




            } else {

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(DataStateOne.this);
                alert.setTitle("Error");
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setMessage("You did not fill all the required data.");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();


            }



        }
    });

    mDeleteS1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteButtonClicked();
        }
    });



}

public void printDatabase() {
    String dbString = myDb.databaseToString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dbString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void addButtonClicked() {
    Energies energies = new Energies(mS1ActualEnthalpy.getText().toString());
    Energies energies2 = new Energies(mS1IdealEnthalpy.getText().toString());
    Energies energies3 = new Energies(mS1ActualEntropy.getText().toString());
    myDb.addEnergy(energies);
    myDb.addEnergy(energies2);
    myDb.addEnergy(energies3);
    printDatabase();

}

public void deleteButtonClicked() {
    String inputText = mS1ActualEnthalpy.getText().toString();
    String inputText2 = mS1IdealEnthalpy.getText().toString();
    String inputText3 = mS1ActualEntropy.getText().toString();
    myDb.deleteEnergy(inputText);
    myDb.deleteEnergy(inputText2);
    myDb.deleteEnergy(inputText3);


}

public void updateProgress(){
    int increase = myDb.increaseProgress(1);
}




}
```

Comment: heres where the `startActivityForResult` can be useful https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult` and in return pass an intent from the receiving activity with extras as the progress bar progress. When you'll receive the progress just update update the progress bar `progressBar.setProgress(porgressBar.getProcess + returnProgress);`